# Swing equivalent of the .NET ListBox

Tags: java, .net, swing, listbox, jlist

What is the Swing equivalent of the .NET [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that has the ability to add new items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) inside of a [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

To add and remove items dynamically, you will want to make use of a [DefaultListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) as follows:

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
someComponent.add(scroll);

listModel.addElement("new");
listModel.remove(0);
```

Comment: why can't I see the addElement method in netBeans? Is it of a JList?

Comment: Consider the example above. addElement() is a method of DefaultListModel.